# Python - GUI to Backend, passing input

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, self

I've made a GUI from tkinter and are then trying to pass values entered into Entry widgets when a button is pressed to a separate module which is carrying out calculations.

An extract of the separate module calling the input is below:

```
# Calculation Module
xf = Extract_Inputs(self,'xf')
```

The function this refers to in the GUI is:

```
# GUI Module
def Extract_Inputs(self,x):     

      xf_In = float(self.e_xf.get()) 

      if x == 'xf':
          x = xf_In/100
```

Where `e_xf` refers to the Entry widget

This brings up the error: `name 'self' is not defined` when `xf = Extract_Inputs(self,'xf')` is used.

How do I go about getting round this without making the first part into a function which I pass self into?

The complete files can be found here: https://github.com/AyrtonB/McCabe-Thiele/tree/master/MT%20v1.2

Comment: Simply remove `self` from `xf = Extract_Inputs(self,'xf')`. I think you need to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self)

Comment: However, `self` is needed for `Extract_Inputs()` as an input so it knows which frame to refer to?

Comment: Looking at your full code, `Extract_Inputs(self,x)` is not inside a class therefore the use of `self` is not warranted.

Comment: would you recommend just writing values to a .csv file and using that between the two modules or making a class for Extract_Inputs(self,x)?

Comment: Make a class. Have a top level class, your application, that refers to an instance of your 'backend' class. Then you might have something inside your application class methods that does something like `self.backend.write(data)`