# Connect my Tkinter GUI to my main program

Tags: python, tkinter

I have coded my GUI and main program seperately. It is a scheduled clicker that clicks a list of coordinates when a specific time is reached. Can I and should I code them in the same file? If not, then how can I connect my main program to the GUI and get access to the values in the GUI from my main program?
GUI code:

```
from tkinter import *
from db import Database

db = Database("coordinates.db")
def start():
    print("Start")

def populate_list():
    print("Populate")

app = Tk()

#Time to run
time_text = StringVar()
time_label = Label(app, text="Time", font=("bold", 14), pady=20, )
time_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
time_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=time_text)
time_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20)

#Interval
interval_text = StringVar()
interval_label = Label(app, text="Interval", font=("bold", 14))
interval_label.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=W)
interval_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=interval_text)
interval_entry.grid(row=0, column=4)

#Coordinates
coordinates_list = Listbox(app, height=8, width=50)
coordinates_list.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3, rowspan=6, pady=20, padx=20)
#Create Scrollbar
scrollbar = Scrollbar(app)
scrollbar.grid(row=3, column=3)
coordinates_list.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.configure(command=coordinates_list.yview)

#Buttons
add_btn = Button(app, text="Start", width=12, command=start)
add_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=20)


app.title("Autoclicker")
app.geometry("700x350")

#Populate data
populate_list()

app.mainloop()
```

Main Program/Backend

```
import time as time_module
import threading
import pyautogui
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode
import datetime
import sched


delay = 1
button = Button.left
start_stop_key = KeyCode(char='s')
exit_key = KeyCode(char='e')
get_position_key = KeyCode(char="g")
reset_coordinates_key = KeyCode(char="r")
coordinates = []

scheduler = sched.scheduler(time_module.time, time_module.sleep)
t = time_module.strptime('2022-04-27 23:35:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
t = time_module.mktime(t)

class ClickMouse(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, delay, button):
        super(ClickMouse, self).__init__()
        self.delay = delay
        self.button = button
        self.running = False
        self.program_running = True

    def start_clicking(self):
        self.running = True

    def stop_clicking(self):
        self.running = False


    def exit(self):
        self.stop_clicking()
        self.program_running = False

    def run(self):
        while self.program_running:
            if self.running:
                for coordinate in coordinates:
                    pyautogui.moveTo(coordinate["x"], coordinate["y"])
                    mouse.click(self.button)
                    time_module.sleep(self.delay)
                self.running = False


mouse = Controller()
click_thread = ClickMouse(delay, button)
click_thread.start()


def on_press(key):
    if key == start_stop_key:
        scheduler_e = scheduler.enterabs(t, 1, click_thread.start_clicking, ())
        scheduler.run()
    elif key == exit_key:
        click_thread.exit()
        listener.stop()
    elif key == get_position_key:
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        coordinates.append({"x" : x, "y" : y})
        print(coordinates)
    elif key == reset_coordinates_key:
        coordinates.clear()


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: You don't need them in the same file. You can just use an import to import the whole class. Doesn't this work with GUIS?

Answer (score 1):

To import the class from another file:

```
from filename import classXY
```

And if you want to use the method of the class:

```
FunctionObject = classXY.method1
FunctionObject(x,y,..)
```

For the last question [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44251723/python-gui-to-backend-passing-input) might help you